# Accessing complex object properties in a class initializer C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

I am trying to show data from my `tblSysproStock` table and display it in a datagrid. Some columns data types in the table are **floats**.

Here is a code snippet of how I want to load the data in my datagrid:

```
    private void FillSysproDataGrid()
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext DC = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            dgSysproStock.ItemsSource = DC.tblSysproStocks.Where<tblSysproStock>(c => c.StockID != null)
                .Select<tblSysproStock, SSData>(m => new SSData()
                {
                    SID = m.StockID,
                    SCode = m.StockCode,
                    SDescription = m.StockDescription,
                    SConvFactAltUom = (float)m.ConvFactAltUom, //-- Here is the problem
                    ...
                });                
        }
    }
```

the class that I use:

```
public struct SSData
{
    public string _ss;

    public int SID { get; set; }
    public string SCode { get; set; }
    public string SDescription { get; set; }
    public float SConvFactAltUom { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now the error that I am getting is -

> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Single
>   which is a non-nullable value type.

Now I don't know how to access my complex object's properties with the code I have to display my data in my **datagrid**. If anyone could be of help, I would be very greatful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are assigning `null` value to `float`, which is not a nullable type (see [Nullable Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx)).

Either use `float?` or change the way that you assign the value, so that you handle the case when it is `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I am quite a neophyte to coding so I don't really know how to implement the 'float?' inside my coding. I tried replacing the `SConvFactAltUom = (float)m.ConvFactAltUom,` with `SConvFactAltUom = (float?)m.ConvFactAltUom,` but it's giving me the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float?' to 'float'?

Comment: Change the type in your `SSData`, from `public float SConvFactAltUom` to `public float? SConvFactAltUom`.